# mysqli and accessing two different tables in same db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

lately I've been getting an error undefined variable mysqli and I was wondering - is it because I'm accessing two different tables in the same database?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'myuser', 'qwerty', 'mydb');

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    //initialise vars
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $checkRecord = $mysqli->query("SELECT information, blahblah FROM table1 WHERE username='$username' AND field1='$field1' AND field2=$field2");

    if(!$checkRecord->num_rows) 
    {
        echo "nothing retreived";
    }   
    else
    {
        $catch = $checkRecord->fetch_object();

        $newsessionnumber = get_new_session_number($username, $ip, $userAgent);

        $senddata = array(
            'newsessionnumber' => $newsessionnumber,
            'info' => $catch->information, 
            'blahblah' => $catch->blahblah, 
            'username' => $username 
        );

        echo json_encode($senddata); 
    }   
}

function get_new_session_number($username, $ip, $userAgent)
{   
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sessionnumberdispatch VALUES (NULL, '$username', NOW(), '$ip', '$userAgent')");

    $newsessionnumber = $mysqli->insert_id;
    return $newsessionnumber;       
}
```

Comment: Where and what is your error exactly?

Comment: Hooray for another SQL injection attack vector in your code!

Comment: @Sven, I'm very much a beginner at php and mysql. I would love it if you could expand on your comment.

Comment: @juergen, undefined variable: mysqli

Comment: You are using a variable inside the SQL statement that is not passed through mysqli_real_escape_string() or $mysqli->real_escape_string() in your case. Google `sql injection` for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$mysqli` object is not getting recognized inside `get_new_session_number()`.

Use the `global` keyword:

```
function get_new_session_number($username, $ip, $userAgent)
{   
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sessionnumberdispatch VALUES (NULL, '$username', NOW(), '$ip', '$userAgent')");

    $newsessionnumber = $mysqli->insert_id;
    return $newsessionnumber;       
}
```

Comment: Better yet, don't use globals or mysqli :)

Comment: @Ray Why not use mysqli? It's mysql that's deprecated, not mysqli.

Comment: @Ray It is apparent from the code of the OP, that he is writing more procedural. Using `global` and `mysqli` (which is pretty secure, maybe not as much as `PDO`, but still pretty good) does make sense in this context if you ask me..

Comment: what if I get rid of the function and move its contents into the main part?